# How to create a MOSS Feature which loads within every site collection page

Tags: site-collection, feature

I need to create a Survey in a SharePoint site. This survey needs to displayed to every user within the site before the page load, so the user will be forced to complete it. After completing the survey, finally, the user will be able to see the page, and the information he completed the survey will be stored, so he will not have to do it again.I need to ensure that the survey will be displayed wherever the page the user hit. So, the first solution that came to my head was a SharePoint feature, activated in the scope site collection. The feature should override the pageload and display the survey. After complete it, it should load the page.

I created a SharePoint feature following this
http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2008/01/24/creating-and-deploying-feature-in-moss/

Am I going to the right way? I'm not getting how do I link my library with the feature. Do you have any example of how can I do it ?

Comment: You will have to put the logic to check whether user has completed the survey or not in some user control and add it to master page, bcoz the user can open any page directly in the site as you said.

Comment: Do you have some example of how can I do it ? Can I manage html on the page with it ? I found references of how in internet, but if you suggest a link I would appreciate

Comment: did some successfully tests, probably you gave me the answer. (said probably cause I have not finished yet) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was not possible to create a feature which override de onload, I created (Following the advice of Unnie) a User Control and added it to the MasterPage. With some C# and CSS, It worked perfectly.

Again, thanks to Unnie.